# Comparing base64 image strings in Golang

Tags: image, go, base64

I have a service that compares two base64 encoded image strings

My initial attempt revealed that there is differences in metadata while the actual image (JPG) in this case is identical (size,resolution,dimensions,etc).

Is there a way to strip away much of the dynamic metadata so that I can just compare the visual aspect of the image?

Currently, I am using the following...

```
package converter

import (
    "bufio"
    "encoding/base64"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func Base64(path string) (string, error) {
    imgFile, err := os.Open(path)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    defer imgFile.Close()

    // create a new buffer base on file size
    fInfo, _ := imgFile.Stat()
    var size int64 = fInfo.Size()
    buf := make([]byte, size)

    // read file content into buffer
    fReader := bufio.NewReader(imgFile)
    fReader.Read(buf)

    // convert the buffer bytes to base64 string - use buf.Bytes() for new image
    imgBase64Str := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(buf)

    return imgBase64Str,nil
}
```

Comment: jpeg is a lossy compression and varies by encoder/decoder, so you can't exactly compare image data from to different jpeg files (and comparing visual similarity is a very large subject for an SO answer). However, if the file size is exactly the same, then you probably have the same image and are incorrectly comparing the base64. (also it's much more efficient to compare a hash, why compare the entire image data?)

Comment: Two possibilities: 1) the actual image data is identical and only the headers are different, and 2) the image *looks* the same but is actually different at the level of the image data. For the former, you should be able to strip the metadata and compare just the image data. This would require some knowledge of the JPEG format. For the latter, you'll want some sort of "image hashing" algorithm, e.g. PhotoDNA. These algorithms hash images visually and are meant to be robust to scaling and rotation.

Answer (score 3):

[Perceptual Hash](http://www.phash.org/) is a library to calculate a phash; a hash of an image based on visual characteristics. [github.com/carlogit/phash](https://github.com/carlogit/phash) is a golang implementation. It has functions to create and compare two hashes to give a 'distance' indicating how dissimilar two images are.

Out of interest I gave it a try, it's simple to use and effective with some test images. For example:

[image: Queenstown] [image: Queenstown] **`distance: 0`**

[image: Queenstown] [image: Queenstown Gold] **`distance: 2`**

[image: Queenstown] [image: Homer Saddle] **`distance: 32`**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"

    "github.com/carlogit/phash"
)

func main() {
    if len(os.Args) < 3 {
        log.Fatalf("usage: %s <ImageFileA> <ImageFileB>\n", os.Args[0])
    }

    a := hash(os.Args[1])
    b := hash(os.Args[2])
    distance := phash.GetDistance(a, b)

    fmt.Printf("distance: %d\n", distance)
}

//hash returns a phash of the image
func hash(filename string) string {
    img, err := os.Open(filename)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer img.Close()

    ahash, err := phash.GetHash(img)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return ahash
}
```